# Use a functional construct to crate a List of classes from REST response

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I wrote the below code to:

1. Query a REST endpoint
2. Create an instance of the case class `Pair` from the name and value fields in the response
3. The Pair instance added to the list `lb`.

This code is very imperative:

```
case class Pair(name: String, value: Double, update: String)
var lb = new ListBuffer[Currency]()
for (elem <- Data.updates) {
  try {
    val request = "http://...../values/" + elem
    val response = scala.io.Source.fromURL(request).mkString
    val jsonObject = Json.parse(response)
    val value = (jsonObject \ "value").get.toDouble
    val update = (jsonObject \ "update").get
    lb += Pair(elem , value, update)
  } catch {
    case e: IOException => println("Exception occured accessing data for " +elem)
  }
}
```

The above code provides the context of the problem. I've refactored and written a block that runs on Scastie with changes but hopefully conveys the same problem:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, __}

val updates = List("test1" , "test2")

case class Pair(name: String, value: Double, update: String)
var lb = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Pair]()
for (elem <- updates) {
    val request = "http://www.google.com" + elem
    val response :  String = "{\"value\" : 1 , \"update\" : \"test\"}"
    val jsonObject = Json.parse(response)
    val value = (jsonObject \ "value").get.toString().toDouble
    val update = (jsonObject \ "update").get.toString()
    lb += Pair(elem , value, update)
}
println(lb.toList)
```

Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RmBUUem5SxGT2dYLIqLryQ

I need to replace the `ListBuffer` with List and somehow populate the `List` using a functional construct instead of a loop?

Comment: Also, it may be good to use `Future` to make the request and use `Future.traverse`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.map`:

```
 val lb = updates.map { elem => 
     ...
     Pair(elem, value, update)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd first define a method:

```
def getPairFromElem(elem: String): Pair = {
  val request = "http://www.google.com" + elem
  val response:  String = "{\"value\" : 1 , \"update\" : \"test\"}"
  val jsonObject = Json.parse(response)
  val value = (jsonObject \ "value").get.toString().toDouble
  val update = (jsonObject \ "update").get.toString()
  Pair(elem , value, update)
}
```

Then use it:

```
val updates = List("test1" , "test2")
val lb = updates.map(getPairFromElem)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ds9RL3ALQcmKdHQY5rYTnQ).